# Asking a question of subject related to existing tag in SO

Tags: discussion, tags

I see osx tag exists in SO.  Does this make asking a question related to osx such as the following in SO. " Does installing Yosemite requires internet connection once downloaded in current os after installing process has started to complete in any stage afterwards?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Just because a tag exists it does not mean that all possible questions relating to that question are on topic.

In this case, the question is not about programming tools or coding (which are on topic on Stack Overflow), so the question itself would be off topic.  Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center to get a better idea of the types of questions.  This file exists on each site within Stack Exchange and is a good guide for what questions are appropriate.

I would strongly suggest looking at the [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) questions to see what type of questions *are* on topic on Stack Overflow.  Note that in most cases its additional information about the environment, such as installing Jenkins (programming tool) in OSX, or use of Matlab (programming tool) in OSX.

Sites also change over time.  Coming from Programmers.SE, there are *numerous* tags from the "Not Programming Related" days that are no longer applicable to new questions (but a mess to clean up from hundreds of old questions).  Once, just the trilogy sites (SO, SU, SF) where all there was (or even older, to just SO) - and much more was allowed in the scope of each one.  When Ask Different was created, questions about OSX where no longer appropriate on the trilogy sites unless the question still remains correct for it and the operating system tag is supporting information (installing jenkins on OSX).

This can indeed cause confusion when looking at old questions about the topicality of the tag or question within the site, which again suggests that people should be sure to read the help center documents (which change with scope over time) to make sure a given question is on topic.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that a lot of tags exist simply because they were created prior to other [se] sites becoming available. In the case of the osx tag, it was probably prior to [su], and definitely prior to [apple.se]. As there are historical questions from that time that have value, the tags can't be deleted. The applicable guidelines are the ones listed in the [help] at the time the question is being asked. Existence of a tag is not evidence that the question is on-topic now according to current guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite does that addition help with the material you are mentioning in the comments? If you still think there is more (or if I've got some of it wrong), I would welcome your input or edits.

Comment: I might have phrased it differently, so it was a little more generic (and a little less specific to the poster's topic), but I think you covered it. :-)